# Custom-Field option not found in custom post type WP 4.6.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom post type call **'Movie'**.Now,I want to add custom meta field in this call `Movie Reviews`.I have following code for custom post type.

```
 function Create_Movies_Posttype()
 {
     register_post_type('Movies',
     array(
     'labels'=>array('name'=>__('Movies'),'singular_name'=>__('Movie')),
     'public'=>true,
     'has_archive'=>true,
     'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'movies'),
     'support'=>array('title','custom-fields','edit'),
     )

     );


 }
 add_action('init','Create_Movies_Posttype');
```

**Added Meta Box**

```
function adding_custom_meta_boxes( $post ) {

        add_meta_box( 
            'my-meta-box',
            __( 'My Meta Box' ),
            'render_my_meta_box',
            'post',
            'normal',
            'default'
        );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes' );
```

Any one please help me with this custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `add_meta_boxes()` action to register metaboxes for a post type.

`add_meta_box()` function to define the box, and `save_post` action to save it.

You'll find everything you need by reading example on Codex [add_meta_boxes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes)

You need also to add supports parameter to the register post type arguments and add custom-field in the array defining the supports for it, all the native supports can be found  [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_supports)

Comment: Yes,But there is no custom field option in side screenoption

Comment: supports not support

Comment: Ask another it's better I think